# Calculating the shortest distance between n GPS points

Tags: math, gps, geolocation, geometry, geography

I have for example 4 points: A (latitute1, longitude1), B (latitute2, longitude2), C (latitute3, longitude3), D (latitute4, longitude4).

If I am a driver and I go from point A, I need an algorithm that calculates the most efficient way for me to visit all the points B, C, D starting from A. So that the distance is the smallest possible.

The algorithm should tell me the most effective order: A --> C --> B --> D (for example).

What matters is the total distance traveled is the lowest possible.

Thanks so much!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look into Dijkstras algorithm?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm